# Redirect url containing string to same url without string

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting

I need to redirect my addresses from a website to another one.

My current urls are like this:
mysite.com/test/.../.../...
or [www.mysite.com/test/...//...//](http://www.mysite.com/test/...//...//)

so I need to redirect all of my pages to mysite.com/.../.../... or [www.mysite.com/.../..](http://www.mysite.com/.../..). so actually I need to redirect to the same url but without the test/.

Any ideas on doing it preferably via .htaccess?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

redirect from root folder yoursite.com/...//...

https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/beginners-guide-redirects-htaccess